# 2 local servers (logic server on C++ and Web Server for Web pages) data interchange. How to?

Tags: c++, qt, http, web-applications, server

we have an application made with Qt C++ and Http server with logic (logic server) Qt C++.
Yet it worked without web page (web app) and now we want to launch a web application (in browser)

I see no solution with 2 separate servers and fast operating data interchange.

What approach should we pick up to solve this problem? And what web server should we take to be able to interchange data efficiently with C++ logic server? Or is there some solution for Qt C++ to make our server on C++ generate wep pages?

What is now?

Server side

http logic server C++ with Sqlite database

Client side

Android, ios, windows applications working with logic server.

What we need?

Server side

http logic server C++ with Sqlite database + functionality to generate web pages (separate server or addon to C++ server)

Client side

Android, ios, windows applications working with logic server. + web application in browser

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Wt, a C++ Web Toolkit](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). It mimics the Qt API to allow webdevelopment in C++. You can instantiate widgets which compile into a webserver that renders these widgets, using html and css, on the client's browser.